# Capture Username in server side log file

Tags: javascript, logging

I have an internal javascript application and I'm trying to find a way to record the username of the user to a server side log file so we can keep track of what employees are using the web app.  Thanks for any help.

best regards,

Comment: Why not send username with ajax to server?

Comment: @BenniKa: that might work.  How can I do that in AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way to do that is to do an AJAX call to a script on the server that can write the data passed to the log file.

Unless you are using technologies like [nodejs](http://nodejs.org) with [nowjs](http://nowjs.com/) as here you could call server side function directly from the client side. But again some server side scripting will be required.